# Python 3.5: Cannot get all fields from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, python-3.5, pymysql

I have an SQL database with two recipes in it and I wish to be able to take all of them out of the database in the format of a string. My current code will only take one.

```
def connector():
    # Connects to the SQL serevr
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                 user='HarryMiddlemas',
                                 password='qwer',
                                 db='project_schema',
                                 charset='utf8mb4',
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    return connection

    def myRecipes():
        connection = connector()
        try:
            with connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
                sql = "SELECT `recipe_name`, `recipe_ingredients`,`recipe_method` FROM `recipes` WHERE `user_id`=%s"
                cursor.execute(sql, (currentUser))
                result = cursor.fetchall()
                recipeResults = result
                print(recipeResults)
        finally:
            connection.close()
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Do both rows have the same `user_id`?

Comment: Yes, they both have the user_id "2".

Comment: What happens when you run it without the where clause?  Do you get all records back?

Comment: When I run this: sql = `"SELECT `recipe_name`, `recipe_ingredients`,`recipe_method` FROM `recipes`"` I get this error: `line 143, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`